# Blazor page that has component-to-component data passing is throwing event error on load

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor .net 6 server side project in VS 2022. My razor page has two components, and I want to pass data from component1 to component2.

Comp1 has a button that when clicked will fire an event:

```
//Component1.razor
<input type="button" value="PassTheData" @onclick="PassTheData" />

//Component1.razor.cs
[Parameter] public string TheData { get; set; } = string.Empty;
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> PassTheDataEvent { get; set; }
....
private async void PassTheData() {
   TheData = "DATA!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
   await PassTheDataEvent.InvokeAsync(TheData);
}
```

Comp2 has minimal code to only receive the data:

```
//Component2.razor
<h3>Comp 2</h3>
The data is:  @TheDataComp2

//Component2.razor.cs
[Parameter] public string TheDataComp2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

My understanding is that the parent page gets the data from comp1 to comp2. In the comp1 markup, I bind the comp1 property to a parent property, and that parent property is passed to comp2:

```
//Parent1.razor
<Comp1 @bind-TheData="theDataParent"></Comp1>
<br />
<Comp2 TheDataComp2="@theDataParent"></Comp2>

//Parent1.razor.cs
private string theDataParent = string.Empty;
```

However, when I load the parent page, I receive this error:

> [2023-08-24T17:45:15.942Z] Error: System.InvalidOperationException:
> Object of type 'UI.Comp1' does not have a property matching the name
> 'TheDataChanged'.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForUnknownIncomingParameterName(Type
> targetType, String parameterName)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView&
> parameters, Object target)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object
> target)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView
> parameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView
> directAndCascadingParameters)

I don't understand what is this property called TheDataChanged that it is being looked for. Can someone help? If I remove the  `@bind-TheData="theDataParent"` markup, the page loads fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a parameter called `TheData` then the `EventCallback` must be named `TheDataChanged` (parameter name + 'Changed') for bind syntax to work.

```cs
[Parameter] public string TheData { get; set; } = string.Empty;
[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> TheDataChanged { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are correct. I didn't see/notice that in any of the articles/tutorials I came across. That solved it for me, thank you!